# JavaScript Date and browser version function

Tags: javascript, html, date, browser-detection

I can't seem to get this code working. Im trying to make it so that if the browser is IE6 or lower it will use "horarios2.png" for the img src and no other. And if its any other browser that it will check the weekday(0-6) so that it will fill in the specific image for each day. From Monday(1) to Wensday(3) the image is suposed to be "quarta.png". The other day's have their own image. They work seperatly but when I try and put them together I get in trouble and it dosen't render the image.

Script

```
$(document).ready (function horario () {
var date = new Date();
var weekday = (date.getDay());

function (msieversion) {
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent
var msie = ua.indexOf ( "MSIE " )

if ( msie > 0 )
     return parseInt (ua.substring (msie+5, ua.indexOf (".", msie )))
else
     return 0
}
if ((msieversion() == 0 )&&(weekday==0)) {
    document.getElementById('horarios').src = "img/domingo.png";}
else if ((msieversion() == 0 )&&(weekday==4)) {
    document.getElementById('horarios').src = "img/quinta.png";}
else if ((msieversion() == 0 )&&(weekday==5)) {
    document.getElementById('horarios').src = "img/sexta.png";}
else if ((msieversion() == 0 )&&(weekday==6)) {
    document.getElementById('horarios').src = "img/sabado.png";}
else if((msieversion() <= 6 )&&(weekday>=0)) {
    document.getElementById('horarios').src = "img/horarios2.png";}
else {
    document.getElementById('horarios').src = "img/quarta.png";}
});
```

HTML

```
<img id="horarios" border="0" alt="" width="343" height="45" />
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some code.  The second if statement is unreachable.

Comment: `if ((msieversion() = 0` should be `if ((msieversion() == 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think you meant [DEMO HERE (mouseover the image)](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/x7cKe/)

```
function msieversion() {  
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
  return (msie == -1)?0: 
      parseInt(ua.substring (msie+5, ua.indexOf (".", msie )))
}
function getImg(idx) {
  return [
  "img/domingo.png",
  "img/quarta.png",
  "img/quarta.png",
  "img/quarta.png",
  "img/quinta.png",
  "img/sexta.png",
  "img/sabado.png"
  ][idx];
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var weekday = new Date().getDay();
  if (msieversion() == 0 ) $("#horarios").attr("src",getImg(weekday));
  else $("#horarios").attr("src",(msieversion() <= 6 )? "img/horarios2.png":"img/quinta.png");
});
```

Comment: @Jonny Sorry, I had some typos. I fixed the typos and changed the rest of the script to jQuery too

Comment: It work but dosen't detect the version of IE, all IE versions are getting image replacement instead of only IE6

Comment: I cannot test until about 10 hours from now since I do not have IE here and need some sleep

Comment: after your sleep you can try using IE tester its a freeware that has all IE version from 5.5 to 9

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be refined more.

But before that, you may want to use the "official" way of detecting the version of IE:
([From Detecting Internet Explorer More Effectively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
// Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
  var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  return rv;
}
```

Now, lets work on the logic:

- If the browser is IE6 or lower it will use "horarios2.png" for the img src and no other.
- And if its any other browser that it will check the weekday(0-6) so that it will fill in the specific image for each day.

  - From Monday(1) to Wensday(3) the image is suposed to be "quarta.png".
  - The other day's have their own image

:

```
function horario ()  {
   var imageName = "";
   if(getInternetExplorerVersion() <= 6) {
      imageName = "img/horarios2.png";
      return;
   }

   var date = new Date();
   var weekday = (date.getDay());
   switch(weekday)
   {
      case 0:
          imageName = "img/domingo.png";
          break;
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
          imageName = "img/quarta.png";
          break;
      case 4:
          imageName = "img/quinta.png";
          break;
      case 5:
          imageName = "img/sexta.png";
          break;
      case 6:
          imageName = "img/sabado.png";
          break;
      default:
          imageName = "img/horarios2.png";
   }
   document.getElementById('horarios').src = imageName;
}
```

Comment: If you say "Doesn't work" you will also have to say why. Error message? Unexpected result?

Comment: Are you sure the image name is correct? Can you debug (using Firebug/Chrome Console) and check whether the execution is ok?

Comment: The execution seems fine I don't get any errors but it just dosen't render the image at all. Ive checked and double checked the names and id but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a page from the [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) (this example doesn't require any html5 specific parts) where you use the `[if IE]` proprietary markup to detect IE version, then read from the `<html>` element's `className` in javascript

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/2qeHh/)

**HTML:**

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html lang="en-us" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html lang="en-us" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html lang="en-us" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]--> 
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en-us" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var htmlElement = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0],
    horariosImg = document.getElementById('horarios'),
    imgSrc = '';

if (htmlElement.className.indexOf('ie6') > -1) {
    // do ie 6 (and lower) stuff
    imgSrc = 'img/horarios2.png';
} else {
    // do all other browser stuff
    switch ((new Date).getDay()) {
        case 0: // Sun
            imgSrc = 'img/domingo.png';
            break;
        case 1: // Mon
        case 2: // Tues
        case 3: // Wed
        case 4: // Thurs
            imgSrc = 'img/quinta.png';
            break;
        case 5: // Fri
            imgSrc = 'img/sexta.png';
            break;
        case 6: // Sat
            imgSrc = 'img/sabado.png';
            break;
    }
}
horariosImg.src = imgSrc;
```

Comment: my mistake I forgot to wrap it in a funtion and load it. Its all ok! Thanks alot!